# Can you sort and throw all the `nil` results in the back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to start sorting all my results by a new field. Unfortunately, a lot of my older fields have a `nil` for a timestamp. How can I perform this method and put all the `nils` in the back?

```
.sort{|a,b| b.offering_referral_timestamp <=> a.offering_referral_timestamp}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a <=> b 
returns -1 if a < b
returns 0 if a == b
returns 1 if a > b
```

so I think this should work (if you want all nil at the end, they should be bigger than other elements):

```
.sort{|a,b| a.offering_referral_timestamp.nil? ? 1 : (b.offering_referral_timestamp.nil? ? -1 : a.offering_referral_timestamp <=> b.offering_referral_timestamp)}
```